# KAA application Json/SDK JAVA

Tags: kaa

Am trying to create a new application on Kaa server, I'm facing the following issue:

```
--Can't upload a json file schema
>>>>>>ERROR: Provided parameters are invalid for requested operation: Failed to compile the schema: Compiler not found 
--Can't generate Android or Java SDK 
>>>>>>ERROR: Unexpected service error occurred: Compiler not found
--Can't delete an old Application, Schema or any configuration
```

Comment: its OK running now after install java jdk-8u60-linux-x64.rpm, but still can't delete application and config

Answer (score 0):

You can change application configuration by adding new schema as describes in the [create-schemas](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/#create-schemas) section of Your first Kaa application documentation. The capability to remove applications is not present in Kaa. See [story](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-580) for details.